# Generating random numbers based on 'rule-of-thumb' proportions

Tags: r, python, random-generation

I will try to be as clear as I possibly can:

- I want to populate a matrix of about 10 million rows by 43 columns as a test to an application
- The first task is to generate a random number around 10 million
- Second I need to fill out the columns. Let's say for column 2, random ints can only be generated between 1 and 25. Also, the distribution/frequency of value = 1 is about 80% of the 10 million, 9 to 25 is about 15% where 9 is 90% of the 15%, and 5% randomly distributed between everything else.
- Let's say for columns 5 to 10, we know that if column_2 = 10 then there is about 80% possibility that the values will be roughly some_int_1.
- I have a lot of these little rules.
- None of them are discrete.
- How can I go about generating such matrix?

Answer (score 5):

If I think I've got what you're saying, here's some R code for basic stuff:

```
ss<-1000 #just in case of problems, change to 1000000 for your purposes
a1<-rnorm(ss)
a2<-sample(1:25, ss, replace =T, 
  prob=c(0.8, rep(0.05/length(2:8), length(2:8)), 0.135,  
  rep((0.15-0.135)/length(10:25), length(10:25))))
a5<- ifelse(a2 == 10, sample(1:5, 1, prob=c(0.8, rep(0.2/4, 4))), sample(1:5, 1))

df1<-cbind(a1, a2, a5)
```

If you want computational efficiency, well that's a little different.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in Python is the following. You would of course have to change $nRow$ to 10 million. Depending on your computational needs and resources, may be better to not keep everything in memory. Generate each row, write out to file, and move on.

```
from numpy import random

nRow = 10
nCol = 43


def c1def(i):
    return(random.randn())

def c2def(i):
    x = random.rand()
    if x < 0.8:
        return(1)
    elif x < 0.95:
        if random.rand() < 0.9:
            return(9)
        else:
            return(random.randint(10,26))
    else:
        return(random.randint(2,9))

def c5def(vector):
    if vector[1] == 10:
        if random.rand() < 0.8:
            return(1)
    else:
        return(0)

rowVec = [0] * nCol
matrix = [rowVec] * nRow

for i in range(nRow):
    for j in range(nCol):
        matrix[i][0] = c1def(i)
        matrix[i][1] = c2def(i)
        matrix[i][4] = c5def(matrix[i])
        matrix[i][5] = c5def(matrix[i])
        matrix[i][6] = c5def(matrix[i])
        matrix[i][7] = c5def(matrix[i])
        matrix[i][8] = c5def(matrix[i])
        matrix[i][9] = c5def(matrix[i])
```